# TFS build error "Delete Binaries Directory fails, the directory is not empty"

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a nightly build rule which "randomly" fails with "The directory is not empty" (sorry can't post image but here's the output from the log)

> Overall Build Process
>   00:51   Update Build Number 
>   00:00   Create the Drop Location
>   00:00   Run On Agent (reserved build agent...)
>   00:50   Delete Test Results Directory
>   00:00   Delete Binaries Directory
>   00:02
>       ! The directory is not empty

I currently have 2 build agents that are used for this particular nightly build and I have seen it fail on both agents.  I can manually queue this build in the morning and it builds no problem (again I have seen this on both agents)

I can't find any specific post related to this issue (only an issue where MSBuild fails to remove binaries directory, but this isn't as far as MSBuild) or anything on the web.

Does anyone have any ideas what is causing this?

There are no users logged onto the build PC or any directories within the agents open at the time of the build.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error occurr if I have the directory open via the administrator share on my computer as well. \BuildServer\c$

Comment: Thanks for sharing but I'm not aware of having anything open or connected, I can re-que the build (without making any other changes) and it completes with success...